# What is the dual lattice of Kagome lattice?

Tags: tiling, tessellations, lattices-in-lie-groups

We know that the dual lattice of a triangular lattice is the honeycomb lattice. What is the dual lattice of Kagome lattice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its dual is called the [rhombille tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombille_tiling).  It looks like the playing field for [Q*bert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q*bert):

[image]

Comment: this is also commonly referred to as a dice lattice